# Play! Framework run throws UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, macos, playframework

Background, this application is running on Play! Framework 1.2.4 on a Mac OS X 10.5.8

The command I'm running: `sudo play run`

The exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:676)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:317)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:280)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:375)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:321)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.loadPlugins(PluginCollection.java:158)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:294)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:158)
```

The application.conf for the application and all dependent modules are set to `java.source=1.6`

`sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` yields `java version "1.6.0_26"`

I've even pointed /System/Java/Home to the 1.6 installation.

What else could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have any third party dependencies? This error typically occurs, if some dependencies are compiled with java 7, and you are running with java 6.

Comment: We have an assortment of dependencies in use but they are pulled down via Ivy and other team members don't have this issue.  Everyone else on the team is running this with Java 6 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Java version(s) do you have in your PATH? We got a similar issue (not with Play, though) in which all the settings of the application seemed to point to 1.6 but the PATH had a reference to 1.5 that was loaded first due to its position inside the PATH string.

Check your PATH. And, I'm not a Mac user, but it's necessary to use `sudo`? In Ubuntu I run Play without. If possible, this may help to reduce unexpected conflicts due to `root` user paths and configuration.

Comment: Just figured out the issue.  Yes it was sudo related.  sudo java -version showed that root was using Java 1.5.  Updating the root profile fixed this.